# убрать атрибут multiplace на мобильной версии сайта

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap

Помогите пожалуйста.
Имеется select с multiple на больших экранах.
Задача -  убрать атрибут  multiple
на мобильной версии сайта.

Comment: Покажите ваш код

Comment: это обычный селект:

Comment: <select class="form-select" multiple aria-label="Default multiple select">
                            <option selected>Текст</option>
                            <option value="1">Текст</option>
                            <option value="2">Текст</option>
                          </select>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Такой функционал можно реализовать следующим образом:

```
const select = document.querySelector('.form-select'); //Получаем селект
const width = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 420px)'); //Задаем нужную ширину после которой должен исчезать атрибут

function setMultiple(size) {

  if (size) { //Если меньше 420px, то будет возвращено true и атрибут удалится
    select.removeAttribute('multiple')
  } else {
    select.setAttribute('multiple', '')
  }
}

width.addEventListener('change', function (event) { //Создаём обработчик в котором вызываем функцию изменения атрибута
  setMultiple(event.matches)
})
```

Comment: Обновляю страницу в браузере при  размере экрана меньше 420 и multiple возвращается

Comment: После объявления констант добавьте if (width.matches) { select.removeAttribute('multiple') }

Comment: Теперь все работает.  Logos, спасибо огромное за помощь!

Comment: @Надежда рад, что смог помочь, отметьте пожалуйста ответ как принятый